# Camera is null when going back to activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-camera

So I was following the android developers build a camera application sample and have my camera activity up and running. However when I go to another activity then hit the back button I am getting a crash because the camera is null in the surface view's on surface created. Can someone explain how this error is happening. Thanks!

** Activity

```
public class PhotoCaptureActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    public static final String TAG = "PhotoCaptureActivity";

    CameraPreview mPreviewScreen;
    Button mCaptureButton;
    ImageView mPreviewThumbnail;
    TextView mPhotoActionLabel;
    TextView mImageLogText;
    Camera mCamera;
    Camera.PictureCallback mPicture;

    ArrayList<Bitmap> mPictures  = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_capture);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        mCaptureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        mPreviewThumbnail = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumb_nail_image);
        mPhotoActionLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.photo_action_text);
        mImageLogText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.image_log);

        mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                BitmapFactory.Options scalingOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                scalingOptions.inSampleSize = camera.getParameters().getPictureSize().width / mPreviewThumbnail.getMeasuredWidth();
                final Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, scalingOptions);
                mPictures.add(bmp);
                mPreviewThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                mPreviewThumbnail.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                mCamera.startPreview();
                mPhotoActionLabel.setText(getString(R.string.done));
            }
        };

        mCaptureButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mPhotoActionLabel.setOnClickListener(this);
        mImageLogText.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.button_capture:
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                break;
            case R.id.photo_action_text:
                if (mPhotoActionLabel.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.cancel)))
                    finish();
                else {
                    Intent photoReviewIntent = new Intent(this,PhotoReviewActivity.class);
                    startActivity(photoReviewIntent);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.image_log:
                Intent imageLogIntent = new Intent(this,ImageLogActivity.class);
                startActivity(imageLogIntent);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
            mCamera = getCameraInstance();
            if (mCamera != null){
                mPreviewScreen = new CameraPreview(this,mCamera);
                FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
                frameLayout.addView(mPreviewScreen);
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.failed_to_open_camera, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_camera_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

** preview screen java class

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        this.mCamera = camera;
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("Error starting camera", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
        }

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.i("Error starting camera", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        //Handeled in activity
    }
}
```

Comment: before jumping to another activity first You need to call mCamera.release() before you finish from this activity. then recreate camera object in 2nd activity because when you call camera and if it is already open then it will throw npe.

Comment: In Resume method call startPreview() using camera object. It will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onResume()`, an old **mPreviewScreen** may still exist, and cause problems. Consider adding the following to `onPause()`:

```
if (mPreviewScreen != null) {
    FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    frameLayout.removeView(mPreviewScreen);
    mPreviewScreen = null;
}
mCamera = null;
```